How to test Blazor MudSelect with bUnit?
I am struggling with testing a MudSelect component with bUnit.
Example.razor
@using MudBlazor
<MudSelect @bind-Value="_selectedValue"
           Label="Age">
    @for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var age = i;
        <MudSelectItem T="int?" Value="@age">@age</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code {
    private int? _selectedValue;
}

Wrapper.razor
@using MudBlazor
<MudPopoverProvider/>
<Example />

ExampleTests.cs
using FluentAssertions;
using MudBlazor;
using MudBlazor.Services;

namespace App.UnitTests.Example;

public class ExampleTests : TestContext
{
    public ExampleTests()
    {
        Services.AddMudServices();
        JSInterop.SetupVoid("mudPopover.initialize", _ => true);
        JSInterop.SetupVoid("mudKeyInterceptor.connect", _ => true);
        JSInterop.Setup<int>("mudpopoverHelper.countProviders");
        JSInterop.SetupVoid("mudKeyInterceptor.updatekey", _ => true);
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void TestMudSelect()
    {
        var cut = RenderComponent<Wrapper>();
        
        var select = cut.FindComponent<MudSelect<int?>>();
        var menu = cut.Find("div.mud-popover");
        var input = cut.Find("div.mud-input-control");
        
        menu.ClassList.Should().Contain("select-popover-class");

        select.Instance.Value.Should().BeNull();
        
        cut.WaitForAssertion(() => cut.Find("div.mud-popover").ClassList.Should().NotContain("mud-popover-open"));
        
        input.Click();
        menu.ClassList.Should().Contain("mud-popover-open");
        
        cut.WaitForAssertion(() => cut.FindAll("div.mud-list-item").Count.Should().BeGreaterThan(0));
        
        var items = cut.FindAll("div.mud-list-item").ToArray();
        items[1].Click();
    }
}

The above is inspired by MudBlazors's tests, and this discussion.
No matter what I try there are never any list items rendered. I am completely stuck now.
Any help would be much appreciated.
